# Get all friends list from Facebook and get list of those who is having birthday on today and other aslo

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried to get friend list from facebook using Graph API but it's not returning friend list. I have tried following code to get list after a successful login in facebook...

```
FBRequest *req = [FBRequest requestForMe];

[req startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *result, NSError *error) {
       if (!error)
       {
             [[VSFacebook sharedFacebook] setFbUser:result];
             FriendsViewController *f = [[FriendsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FriendsViewControlleriPad" bundle:nil];
             [self presentViewController:f animated:YES completion:nil];
       }
}];
```

and after connecting on FriendsViewContrller.m file I have call graph API to get friend list as following

```
self.facebookBlock = completionBlock;
NSString *fields = @"id,name,picture,birthday";
NSString *format = @"json";
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/friends?fields=%@&format=%@&access_token=%@", @"me", fields, format, self.fbAccessTokenData.accessToken];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

id result = nil;
if (data)
{
    result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
}
self.facebookBlock([result valueForKey:@"data"], error);
```

I got on result only three value pair like "summary", "data", "paging"

Comment: You can only get friends that granted user_friends permission. And you can only get birthday from people that granted user_birthday to your app

Comment: i think its help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516601/facebook-ios-sdk-get-friends-list-in-graph-api-v2-4/32516873#32516873

Comment: That's i know but when i used facebook developer tool to check that time i have got friend list...@WizKid

Answer (score 2):

> You cann't get all friends list from facebook using Graph API. It's
>   not possible to get all Friend's List , according to new API version

Comment: but i have not got any list of friend...@Niharika

Comment: You can only get the total number of your friends. You can't get the friend list.